# Asp:GridView button with CommandArgument

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm trying to get an id in the click of my button. My button is inside a GridView

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            ID="UsersGridView" AllowPaging="true"
                            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
                            UseAccessibleHeader="true" GridLines="None">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User.FullName" HeaderText="User" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Book.Title" HeaderText="Book" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="BooksReserved.DateOut" HeaderText="Return Date" 
                            FooterStyle-BackColor="#ff0000" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="userProfile" runat="server" OnCommand="userProfile_Command"
                                    CommandArgument='<% Eval("User.Id") %>'
                                    Text="Open User Profile" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind method Page_Load, I load the data for my gridview from 3 tables:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Users Grid
    var query = from u in db.Users
                join br in db.BooksReserveds on u.Id equals br.UserId
                join b in db.Books on br.BookId equals b.Id
                where br.DateOut < DateTime.Today
                orderby br.DateOut
                select new { User = u, BooksReserved = br, Book = b };

    UsersGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
    UsersGridView.DataBind(); }
```

And in the click of the button, I try to get the id:

```
protected void userProfile_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        var query = from u in db.Users
                    where u.Id == id
                    select u;
    } catch(Exception any)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(any.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the exception: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Could you render just `<ItemTemplate><% Eval("User.Id") %></ItemTemplate>` to see the output whether it displays integer value?

Comment: It gives me a syntax error. Expected a ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget `#`. Syntax should be `<%# %>`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="userProfile" runat="server" OnCommand="userProfile_Command"
   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("User.Id") %>'
   Text="Open User Profile" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
```

Comment: Well this answer was not here when I started typing my answer. This is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here in your `Page_Load` event handler you are doing `select new` into your `query` variable, making that variable an anonymous object:

```
// Users Grid
//by using var here and select new this object is anonymous.
var query = from u in db.Users
            join br in db.BooksReserveds on u.Id equals br.UserId
            join b in db.Books on br.BookId equals b.Id
            where br.DateOut < DateTime.Today
            orderby br.DateOut
            select new { User = u, BooksReserved = br, Book = b };

UsersGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
UsersGridView.DataBind();
```

You need a defined object that you can cast to in the ItemTemplate of the Gridview. Something like this:

```
public class UserGridViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public BooksReserved BooksReserved { get; set; } //sounds like it could be a collection, but I do not know.
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

Then, back to your `Page_Load` UserGrid select query:

```
// Users Grid -- Notice the select new UserGridViewModel()
var query = from u in db.Users
        join br in db.BooksReserveds on u.Id equals br.UserId
        join b in db.Books on br.BookId equals b.Id
        where br.DateOut < DateTime.Today
        orderby br.DateOut
        select new UserGridViewModel() { User = u, BooksReserved = br, Book = b };
```

Then in your Gridviw, the ItemTemplate is essentially a naming container and for that container you need to get the DataItem, which will be a `UserGridViewModel` object (which you will have to cast the dataItem to your model). See this snippet of just your command argument(also note this server opening tage `<%#`):

```
CommandArgument='<%# ((UserGridViewModel)Container.DataItem).User.Id %>'
```

any other variable from your UserGridViewModel can be accessed in a similar fashion inside of the ItemTemplate.